# Asp.net core application Ajax post is hitting wrong action after publishing

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, http-post, web-hosting, subapplication

I have hosted a new ASP.Net core application as a sub-site of another application in IIS. In local everything has been working fine. But, after publishing this application as a subsite, Ajax post request is hitting the wrong controller and action.

Using Ajax to call the BGetDetails action in BController. But the request is hitting on the AGetDetails action in AController.

I have tried a lot of ways to fix this issue, but can't do it.

If hosted this application as a separate domain everything has been fine. I have to face the issue only when hosting the application as a sub-site of another application.

I have attached the same codes. Please find those below,

**Route config**

```
               app.UseMvc(routes =>
               {
                        routes.MapRoute(
                            name: "yyyyyyy",
                            template: "Platform/GetDetails",
                            defaults: new { controller = "B", action = "BGetDetails" });
               });
                app.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "xxxxxx",
                        template: "{arug1}/{arug2}",
                        defaults: new { controller = "A", action = "AGetDetails" });
                });
```

**Ajax call:**

```
     data = { "arug1": arug1, "arug2": arug2, "arug3": arug3, "arug4": arug4, "arug5": arug5 };                
    
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/sub-site/Platform/GetDetails",
                    data: data,
                    success: function (result) {
                         ...
                    }});
```

**Controller:**

**controller-1**

```
public class AController: Controller
{
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AGetDetails(string arug1, string arug2)
        {
          ...........
        }
}
```

**Controller-2**

```
public class BController : Controller
{
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult BGetDetails(string arug1, string arug2, string arug3, string arug4, bool arug5)
        {
        .........
        }
}
```

Help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance,

Comment: It can work in my local IIS, can you show the web.config?

Comment: When I set it as a sub-site, it can send ajax. But it cannot work when I set it as a separate domain.